# Como fazer uma contagem do números de sequências em R?

Tags: r, séries-temporais

Tenho uma planilha com a quantidade de chuva para cada dia do mês. Se houver pelo menos 5 dias consecutivos com o valor da célula igual a 0, o contador recebe 1. A próxima sequência com 5 ou mais dias consecutivos faz incrementar mais 1 no contador e assim por diante. Se houverem 3 destas sequências a contagem final será 3.  Como implementar isso no R?

[image: Segue uma imagem de como os dados estão na planilha com valores para 31 dias de um mês]

Comment: Bem-vinda ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score 1):

Minha cara, veja as recomendações no comentário pois elas são muito importantes para garantir a qualidade das perguntas e das respostas. Como você está chegando aqui no SO eu vou dar um desconto e vou responder a pergunta, que diga-se de passagem não é nada trivial, especialmente para quem está começando com o R.

**EXEMPLO REPRODUTÍVEL**

A primeira coisa que você deveria ter feito na sua pergunta é fornecer um exemplo reprodutível, portanto vou criar uma série de números que bem poderia ser de uma contagem.

```
data =  sample(x = 1:10, size = 100000, replace = T)
```

o que esse código faz basicamente é retirar uma amostra, com reposição, de 100 mil números entre 1 a 10. Obviamente vai haver algumas repetições e eu quero saber quantas repetições seguidas de  5 números há.

**ACHANDO QUALQUER REPETIÇÃO DE 5 NÚMEROS SEGUIDOS**

Para isso vou usar o comando `rollapply` do pacote `zoo`. Esse função cria uma "janela" que vai andando ao longo da sequência de números. Dentro dessa janela você pode executar qualquer função como a média por exemplo. Aqui no caso vou usar a média:

```
> data[1:10]
[1]  8  2  8  6 10 10  4  6  7 10 
> rollapply(data = data[1:10], 5, mean)
[1] 3.6 4.6 5.8 6.2 4.6 4.0
```

observe qua a função retornou somente 6 números. Isso ocorreu porque eu só consigo andar com a "janela" até 6 vezes quando o conjunto de dados tem somente 10 números. Veja essa figura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu rodei a janela como a função `rollapply` faz. No caso, para cada janela, que pode rodar 6 vezes, ele calculou a média. Agora como isso pode te ajudar achar as sequências de 5 dias consecutivos com o mesmo número??

Basta calcular em cada janela alguma coisa que dê zero quando **todos os números são repetidos**! A função que faz isso é o desvio padrão. Se todos os números são iguais o desvio padrão é 0. Logo basta usar o `rollapply` junto com a função `sd`, isso liquida a fatura! Por exemplo:

```
> dados = c(5,5,5,5,5,1,3,4,5,5,5,5,5)
> rollapply(dados, 5, sd)
[1] 0.0000000 1.7888544 1.7888544 1.6733201 1.6733201
[6] 1.6733201 0.8944272 0.4472136 0.0000000
```

aqui são duas sequências de cincos e portanto apareceram dois desvios padrão iguais a 0. Agora é só contar quantas vezes o zero apareceu.

```
> sum(rollapply(dados, 5, sd) == 0)
[1] 2
```

Agora fazendo o mesmo nos dados que eu gerei, que é uma sequência muito maior e que não daria para visualizar, temos:

```
> sum(rollapply(data, 5, sd) == 0)
[1] 6
```

**ACHANDO ESPECIFICAMENTE UMA SEQUÊNCIA DE ZEROS**

No caso da sua série repetir vários números diferentes seguidos e você estar interessada somente nos zeros e não na repetição de outros números, o que você pode fazer é passar uma função nos dados e introduzir um ruído nos números que não são zeros.

```
data2 <- ifelse(data == 0, data, jitter(data))
sum(rollapply(data2, 5, sd) == 0)
```

agora o número de sequência seguidas somente com zero será retornado já que outros valores que eram anteriormente repetidos agora com ruído já não se repetem mais.

**CUIDADO**

Veja que no exemplo anterior eu gerei 100 mil números por um sorteio aleatório de número de 1 a 10 e, **ainda assim**, encontrei seis sequências repetidas de números! A advertência é: ao encontrar esse tipo de padrão nas duas séries, especialmente se forem séries longas de chuva com mais de 30 anos por exemplo, se faça a seguinte pergunta: esse padrão que eu encontrei é tão improvável ao ponto de eu dizer que ele é significativo? Não é difícil ocorrer de você atribuir significados a ruídos aleatórios nos dados. Há muitos trabalhos acadêmicos por aí com esse problema.

Answer (score -1):

Vou tentar lhe mostrar uma maneira de resolver esse problema sem que dependa de funções exclusivas. Aqui apenas uso o pacote `dplyr` contido no pacote `tidyverse`. Assumindo que os dados estejam no formato que `df` está:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(12)
df <- tibble(dados = c(1,0,0,0,0,0, sample(x = 0:1, size = 1000, replace = T)))

df
#> # A tibble: 1,006 x 1
#>    dados
#>    <dbl>
#>  1     1
#>  2     0
#>  3     0
#>  4     0
#>  5     0
#>  6     0
#>  7     0
#>  8     1
#>  9     1
#> 10     0
#> # … with 996 more rows

df %>% 
    mutate(is_zero = dados == 0) %>% 
    mutate(is_start_of_streak = is_zero & lead(is_zero) & lag(!is_zero)) %>% 
    mutate(streak_id = cumsum(is_start_of_streak)*is_zero) %>% 
    filter(streak_id != 0) %>% 
    group_by(streak_id) %>% 
    summarise(size = n()) %>% 
    mutate(size_g_5 = size >= 5) %>% 
    summarise(total_de_streaks_maior_que_5 = sum(size_g_5))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   total_de_streaks_maior_que_5
#>                          <int>
#> 1                           34
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>