# contar sequências de 5 ou mais zeros em cada linha

Tags: r

Eu tenho um data frame com dados diários, sendo cada linha os mês/ano e cada coluna os dias 1, 2, 3...

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 25 | 12 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 40 | 25 | 5 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 32 |
| 4 | 0 | 10 | 6 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 10 | 3 | 15 | 30 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 18 |

Preciso contar quantas sequências de 5 ou mais zeros há em cada linha usando o RStudio. Encontrei uma pergunta similar ([aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/376531/como-fazer-uma-contagem-do-n%C3%BAmeros-de-sequ%C3%AAncias-em-r)), mas não funcionou aqui. Quando rodo

```
rollapply(dados, 5, mean)
```

Está calculando por coluna e preciso contar por linha. Tentei incluir o rowsum:

```
dados5 <-  rowsum(rollapply(dados, 5, mean)==0)
```

Só que dá erro:

> Error in rowsum.default(rollapply(dados, 5, mean) == 0) :
> 'x' deve ser numérico

No data frame os dados são numéricos, então, não entendi o erro.
Quando utilizo o jitter,

```
dados5 <- ifelse(dados == 0, dados, jitter(dados))
rowsum(rollapply(data5, 5, mean) == 0)
```

aparece mesmo erro:

> Error in jitter(dados) : 'x' deve ser numérico

Se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: O [`jitter`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/jitter.html) não faz o que pensa que faz, veja também [esta pergunta do SO.en](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547699/what-does-the-jitter-function-do-in-r).

Answer (score 3):

Para contar sequências de valores repetidos, há a função [`rle`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rle.html). Aplicando essa função a cada linha, tem-se as repetições de cada valor. Depois é ver quais correspondem a zeros e quantas dessas são maiores que 5.

Nos dados da pergunta há uma sequência de zeros maiores que 5 nas 2ª e última linhas.

```r
apply(dados, 1, \(x) {
  r <- rle(x)
  sum(r$lengths[r$values == 0] > 5)
})
#> [1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

Para obter as sequências de valores menores que ou iguais a 1 é um bocado mais complicado. Mas também pode ser resolvido com um ciclo `apply`, basta primeiro substituir os 1 por 0 e repetir o código acima.

```r
apply(dados2, 1, \(x) {
  x[x <= 1] <- 0
  r <- rle(x)
  sum(r$lengths[r$values == 0] > 5)
})
#> [1] 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Dados

```
x<-'1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
1   10  5   0   0   25  12  0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
3   40  25  5   0   1   0   32
4   0   10  6   3   0   0   2
5   2   0   0   0   3   0   0
6   10  3   15  30  3   0   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   18'
dados <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

y<-'1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
1   10  5   0   0   25  12  0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
3   40  25  5   0   1   0   32
4   0   10  6   3   0   0   2
5   2   0   0   0   1   0   0
6   10  3   15  30  3   0   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   18'
dados2 <- read.table(textConnection(y), header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Olá, @Rui_Barradas, obrigada pela resposta. Está ocorrendo erro no textConnection e depois no último script.
> dados <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
Error in textConnection(x) : argumento 'text' inválido
> r <- apply(dados, 1, rle)
> sapply(r, \(x) sum(x$lengths[x$values == 0] > 5))
Erro: unexpected input in "sapply(r, \"

Comment: @Francisca A notação `\(x)` é a nova notação para funções lambda introduzida no R 4.2, se dá erro use a velha notação `function(x)`. É hora de atualizar o seu R? Quanto ao `textConnection`, isso é só uma maneira de ler os dados para a minha sessão do R, vou editar com os dados em formatto `dput`.

Comment: @Francisca Seja como for, acho o erro *"Error in textConnection(x) : argumento 'text' inválido"* estranho, o argumento `text` não é utilizado nessa linha de código.

Comment: Obrigada, @Rui_Barradas, funcionou.

Comment: @Rui_Barradas, nesse script a função rle conta valores iguais consecutivos, neste caso, o zero. Tem como contar valores diferentes em sequência? Por exemplo, valores =<1 consecutivos. Preciso saber quantas sequências de 5 ou mais valores =<1 consecutivos ocorrem por linha.

Comment: @Francisca Em vez de `x$values == 0` tente `x$values <= 1` e veja se dá.

Comment: @Rui_Barradas Já tentei. Retorna exatamente mesmo resultado. Usando ==0 ou <=1, ele só  conta os zeros.

Comment: @Francisca Os dados de teste não são os melhores para ver isso, só a 2ª linha é que tem zeros e uns consecutivos e como a sequência de zeros é maior que 5 já estava em `== 0`.

Comment: @Francisca Feito, veja agora.